# Looping issue in Grails app on GSP

Tags: grails, for-loop

I am currently working on a grails app and I am having an issue looping through some objects stored on the domain. Below you can see the domain and I have set-up a template that has 2 options on it.(Option1, Option2)

```
class Template {

    String name

    static hasMany = [options:Options]

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
    }

}
```

Now below is the controller where I pass this data to the view for processing:

```
def create() {

        def template = Template.get(1)
        [systemInstance: new System(params), template: template]

    }
```

And finally I had this code on the GSP that was supposed the loop through the 2 Options stored against this data and then if an Option is detected I wanted some code to run. However when I run this code I get strange behaviour:

```
        <%
            System.out.println 'option is: ' + option
        %>

        <g:if test="${option == 'Option1'}">

        <%
            System.out.println 'Inside the IF'
        %>

        </g:if>
```

When I run this code and as you can see I use Print statements to view the data I am using. Instead of getting the values 'Options1' 'Options2' returned I get the below:

```
option is: [
option is: O
option is: p
option is: t
option is: i
option is: o
option is: n
option is: 1
option is: ,
option is:  
option is: O
option is: p
option is: t
option is: i
option is: o
option is: n
option is: 2
option is: ]
option is: )
```

I have also tested the code below and this returns '[Options1, Options2]':

```
<%
                System.out.println 'option is: ' + template.options.name
            %>
```

Can someone please help me with this as its very strange. Thanks in advance.

---

******EDIT************

---

The for each loop is below:

```
<g:each var="option" in="${ template.options.name })">

            <%
                System.out.println 'option is: ' + option
            %>

            <g:if test="${option == 'Option1'}">

            <%
                System.out.println 'Inside the IF'
            %>

            </g:if>

</g:each>
```

Comment: You are looping throug the string representation of your list - so option is a char. Please provide us with more code of your gsp - especially the part of the loop (g:each) ...

Comment: Hi I have edited my question with the code requested. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little type within your `g:each` tag. Remove the closing `)`.

With this additional bracket the variable within the `in` attribute is the string:

```
"[Option1,Option2])"
```

So you are looping through the chars of the string instead of of the element of your list.

Without the `)` the variable will be handled as `List` of `Strings`.

Comment: Thanks so much im completely burnt out at the moment and appreciate the helpful eye